# How can I view crash details for a nodejs program on a ubunu azure vm?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, azure

So I have created a program and have run it on a VM running on my PC. It uses nodejs and socket.io, and I have had it all running fine locally.

Anyway I am trying to get it all up and running on an ubuntu azure VM. On the client browser it seems to make the initial websocket connection fine (and says this in the nodejs terminal), however when I try to .emit(...message...) on the client, the nodejs server process seems to crash, and I have no idea how to find out why.

In the ssh terminal, all I get is "DEBUG: Program node app.js exited with code null" Which is absolutely useless. I am still new to linux stuff, so I am asking how can I find out what is going wrong?

I have tried adding console.log() in my nodejs app all over the place to no avail, so I guess I am asking, where in ubuntu (on azure) would I find a crash log for nodejs?

I have looked around a bit in here: /var/log/, but didn't find anything particularly usefull, not sure where in there I should be looking if thats the place.

Comment: If you run the application on local machine, are you able to find the logs? If you can, then you can check the same directly on the Windows Azure machine.

Comment: You might try redirecting node console output to a file, if there's a node exception, this would capture the data.